# замена значения переменной android JSOUP

Tags: android, переменные, jsoup, замена, передача-данных

Нужна ваша помощь. Парсер страниц новостей через JS0UP, в одной из новостей нету ссылки - и происходит краш проекта. Как мне установить ссылку по молчанию или подмену ссылки если (linkHref) не получает данные?

```
Elements table = doc.select("table[style]");
arraylist.clear();
for(Element row: table) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Element jink = row.select("td[style]").first();
    Element xHref = row.select("td[align]").first();
    Element link = jink.select("a").first();
    String linkHref = link.attr("href");

    map.put("news", jink.text());
    map.put("date", xHref.text());
    map.put("link", "http://сайт.ru/news.php?id=" + linkHref.substring(16));
    // Set all extracted Jsoup Elements into the array
    arraylist.add(map);
```

Comment: что передает JSOUP если не находит значение, ноль?

Comment: вроде через switch можно но я что то не могу пока разобраться

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String linkHref = "тут ссылка по-умолчанию"
try {
     linkHref = link.attr("href");
} catch(Exception e) {

}
```